# How to remove blank index from nsmutablearray

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I want to know that remove blank index from this array.please see the code

```
array=( {
        email = "regor@gmail.com";

 fullname = regor;

 photourl = "/download/userphoto/b239eb04-338d-4e93-9387-e0234850edfe.jpg";

  userid = 56b09ea9088e7c6c118c9baa;

 username = regor;

  },

 {

 }
)
```

Comment: what is it ? a log from json ? or log for an array ?

Comment: json value so here i want blank object   remove from  this array .please help me

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the blank index, You can store the first object into a separate dictionary.

Simply do

```
  NSDictionary *dict=array[0];
```

Or If you want to remove the null from an array, try

```
   [array removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];
```